# Валидатор не возвращает сообщения об ошибках

Tags: php, laravel

Не могу получить ошибки от валидатора

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Redirect;
use View;
use App\Code;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Http\Controllers\CodeController; 
class AuthController extends Controller
{

// ....


      public function postRegister(Request $request)
      {

        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            dd($validator->errors->all());
            $messages = $validator->getMessages()->all();
            dd($messages);
            return Redirect::to('signup')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
            //return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }


        /*
        $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
        */


    }

     protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }


}
```

В шаблоне

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error) 
    <div>{{ $error }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Или в шаблоне

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div>Ой, беда!</div>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Или просто

```
{{ $errors }}
```

Ошибки не выводятся не в `dd()` в контроллере. Так же не определены в шаблоне, хотя туда редиректит вроде бы как `witherrors`

Comment: Валидация точно не проходит? Выводится пустой массив?

Comment: Уже пофиксилось. помогло Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
 

    Route::get('/signup/', 'RegistController@getRegister');
    Route::post('/signup/create', 'RegistController@postRegister'); }); Особенность версии 5.2 оказалось. $errors без этого не был виден в шаблоне